# Card problems about combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have a question and I have answers to it, but I want to check if my answer is right. Here is the question: there is a standard deck of 52 cards with 4 suits. The values are 2<3<...<10<jack<queen<king<ace. 2 cards are drawn at random without being placed back.

1. What is the probability that the 2 cards have the same value?
2. What is the probability that the 2 cards have the same suit
3. What is the probability that the 2 cards have values greater or equal to 10
4. What is the probability that the 2 cards have consecutive values (ace can act as the highest and lowest value).

My answer to that is

1. Total is $\binom{52}{2}$. They have the same value. This is $13 \binom{4}{1} \binom{3}{1}$, because this is 13 ways to have values for cards, and there's 4 cards with same value.
2. This is $\binom{13}{1} \binom{12}{1}$ because it is from same suit. This is divided by total
3. $\binom{20}{1} \binom{19}{1}$ because there's 20 cards with greater than 10 value, and then divide by total.
4. This is $(13)(2) (2)\binom{4}{1}$ divide by total. Because it's 13 ways to have consecutive values, and it can be backwards, so I times 2. Then I times 2 again because there's 2 cards I need to choose, and that's $\binom{4}{1}$ ways.

Comment: You are expected to give an explicit formula for the probability, not just to say divide by the total, and probably expected to simplify it.  2 is wrong because you did not consider that there are four suits you can have.

Comment: You seem to be accounting for the order of selection in your numerators but not accounting for the order of selection in your denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much simpler way to look at this problem is to observe that it doesn't actually matter what the first card's value is, only that the second card matches it. The probability that the second card's value matches the first card is $3/51$, because after drawing the first card there are $51$ cards left and $3$ have the same value as the first card.

Using this idea, why don't you give the other problems a try again? You did not arrive at the correct answer for all of them.